# QGIS 3 histogram

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

In prior versions of QGIS I remember being a panel that showed a basic histogram for column in a table as part of a preview of the data. Does something similar exist in QGIS 3. Or how can i get a simple histogram to check the distribution of data in a column>

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Leaving an answer here as have remembered where it was. If you go to properties > symbology and then choose your column and plot as graduated values theres a histogram tab you can toggle:

[image]